# How to test if Flutter app store update will delete app data

Tags: ios, flutter, sqlite, app-store

I am using SQLite on my Flutter app. When I run and rerun/debug my app during development the sqlite file is preserved. When I test it on a physical device with `flutter install` then the database is deleted the second time around.

Is flutter install different than the app store update or will all updates delete the database for the users and how to tackle that?

I am using this code:

```
final systemPath = Platform.isAndroid? await sqlite.getDatabasesPath() : (await getLibraryDirectory()).toString();
final dbPath = path.join(systemPath, 'my.db');
```

Comment: Personally I use sqflite on iOS which is a sqlite plugin. I don't have any data that is destroyed when I install my application or debug it. Are you working on Android?

Comment: @Fugipe I am working both on iOS and android. Can you uninstall the app and re-install it and the db is preserved? For me it gets deleted. In which directory do you store it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes at least with Apple's Testflight when the app is updated the database is preserved while if you run flutter install it's not, it's a new install.